# How to handle having a duplicate int entered into a 2D SortedList of Int, String

Tags: c#, list, error-handling, sortedlist

I've no prior experience with SortedLists and have encountered the error "An entry with the same key already exists" due to trying to enter duplicate Ints into the list. This was an oversight on me thinking this wouldn't happen (which was silly).

The list looks like this:

```
("503", "This is a sentence")
("364", "Oh and another one")
("329", "Yes sentences woo!")
("136", "You gets the point")
```

The function the error is thrown in is:

```
    protected void buildSummary()
    {
        scoreCoord2 = -1;
        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < results.Length; x1++)
        {
            SortedList<int, string> paragraphScoreslist = new SortedList<int, string>();
            for (int x2 = 0; x2 < results[x1].Length; x2++)
            {
                scoreCoord2++;
                paragraphScoreslist.Add(intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2], results[x1][x2]);
            }
            var maxValue = paragraphScoreslist.Max(k => k.Key);
            string topSentence = string.Empty;
            if (paragraphScoreslist.TryGetValue(maxValue, out topSentence))
            {
                TextboxSummary.Text += topSentence + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

and the specific line it breaks on is:

```
    paragraphScoreslist.Add(intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2], results[x1][x2]);
```

The sorted list contains a sentence of a paragraph and the sentences score which the program calculates. I then need the sentence with the highest score, but don't know to handle this error.

I'm fine with both sentences being "top" and both output somehow, or either one being chosen for top unless there is one already higher.

Comment: Question is how many scores are there? do you really have to use a dictionary?

Comment: The SortedList will hold the amount of an average paragraph, so 5 ints + strings, but this is based on user entered text, so it could be massive. I intended to add a limit, so if a paragraph is 6+ to split it up. I originally tried using an array, but that made selecting the string tied to the highest value a pain.

Comment: What you can do is instead of putting a string as value of the dictionary you put a collection of strings in it so you can hold the ex-equo scores. any dictionary will require unique keys.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're saying to do as I've not any experience with lists and are more use to arrays.

Comment: Ah yeah that perfect, now I just don't know how to output the strings held in the list of the top int, which is probs super easy but I haven't a clue if. Getting the top value string of the basic SortedList I had was an achievement for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69762/discussion-between-florian-schmidinger-and-tom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a SortedList, you could create a ScoredSentence class such as

```
public class ScoredSentence 
{
    public string sentence { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }

    public ScoredSentence(string sentence, int score)
    {
        this.sentence = sentence;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

And then you can have it all stored in a List, such as

```
var s1 = new ScoredSentence("this is a sentence", 2);
var s2 = new ScoredSentence("hey there buddy", 4);
var s3 = new ScoredSentence("This is bad", 0);
var scores = new List<ScoredSentence> {s1,s2,s3};
```

You can then pull out the max score with

```
int max = scores.Max(s => s.score);
```

Or find a top scored sentence with

```
var maxScoredSentence = scores.First(s => s.score == max);
```

Here's what it might look like in your code

```
for (int x1 = 0; x1 < results.Length; x1++)
    {
        List<ScoredSentence> scoreslist = new List<ScoredSentence>();
        for (int x2 = 0; x2 < results[x1].Length; x2++)
        {
            scoreCoord2++;
            scoreslist.Add(new ScoredSentence(results[x1][x2],intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2]));
        }
        var maxValue = scoreslist.Max(s => s.score);
        string topSentence = string.Empty;

        TextboxSummary.Text += scoreslist.First(s => s.score == maxValue).sentence + "\n";

    }
```

Comment: This seems great and appears to have worked wonders.. part from the actual output which at the moment is "Summarizer1.MainScreen+ScoredSentence"  How do I get the actual value? :P

Comment: Oops, looks like I forgot to access the property on the string append.  I edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

```
SortedList<int, List<string>> paragraphScoreslist = new SortedList<int, List<string>>();
        for (int x2 = 0; x2 < results[x1].Length; x2++)
        {
            scoreCoord2++;
            if(paragraphScoreslist.ContainsKey(intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2])
            {
               paragraphScoreslist[intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2]].Add(results[x1][x2]);
            }
            else
            {
                paragraphScoreslist.Add(intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2], new List<string>{results[x1][x2]});
            }

        }
```

then to get the top of the pops:

```
 List<string> topSentences;
 if (paragraphScoreslist.TryGetValue(maxValue, out topSentences))
 {
      foreach(string topSentence in topSentences)
      {
         TextboxSummary.Text += topSentence + "\n";
      }
 }
```